# I need to set Accept / Decline EmailMessage object in Microsoft exchange service code

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I need to set Accept /Decline of EmailMessage object in Microsoft exchange service code.
Where message sender wants a response to a message from receiver.

```
    EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(service);
    EmailMessage.Subject = "test";
    EmailMessage.ToRecipients.Add("destination@domain.com");
    EmailMessage.Body = new MessageBody("test");           
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagResponseRequested = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0063000B, MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
    EmailMessage.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagResponseRequested, 1);
    EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Comment: Show the code you've tried and where it isn't working.

Comment: I will try to execute this code, adding the Accept and Decline button is available?

Comment: Have you checked this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633669(v=exchg.80)

Comment: yes,but this is for meetings, I want for Emailmessages